# POST data from c# to PHP and echo it

Tags: c#, php

I know there are a lot of threads about this, but I have a little bit different question.

My code in c# is this:

```
            string url = "http://10.0.0.4/CS_PHP/index.php";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("message=This is the message" + "&" + "username=This is the usrname");

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream webpageStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
```

And I want to see the $_POST array in php, so I tried using this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
var_dump($_POST);
echo "<html><br/></html>";

print_r($_POST);
echo "<html><br/></html>";

print($_POST["message"]);
echo "<html><br/></html>";

$pst = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($pst);
echo "<html><br/></html>";
}
?>
```

But I always get nothing inside the $_POST array.
When I try using Microsoft Network Monitor, I see that the $_POST array does get inside it the data:
[image: $_POST has the data inside it]

And just to be clear what I'm getting on the actual page:
[image]

I think it's somehow related to when I load the page... Don't know...

Thank you for any kind of help

Comment: if that is your actual PHP, you do realize that you're missing a closing brace for the conditional statement. While making sure that is a `.php` file or if not; that you instructed Apache to treat a possible `.html` file as PHP. If `.php`, then you should have been thrown a notice/warning with error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- First, thank you for your reply. The closing brace was missing by mistake, of course it's there haha. As for the rest, there is no error. I think it's more related to when I load the page. I need somehow to see $_POST getting in live the info or something like that.

Comment: You're welcome @JuNeD I had to be sure.

Comment: I've tried your code and everything seems to be OK, or at least I can't understand the problem. Here, Network Monitor shows that `$_POST` contains the data that you desire. So, when is it empty and how did you find out that it is?

Comment: @Ahmad thank you too for your reply. I tried several codes both in C# and PHP but nothing worked for me (always got empty array, the second picture), I thought it's impossible that it works for everyone, beside me, so I decided to check the traffic of my program, to see if it's even sending anything. This is how I managed to find this info from Microsoft Network Monitor, just saw the packet with the info I sent and the response I get back (first pic). You said it works for you, right? You tried sending from C# to PHP? If you did, what you had to do to see the array? When did you load the page?

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST) give ? I would also check the response details in firebug , to diagnose.

Comment: @gyaani_guy The first 3 lines of "HtmlElement" you see in the first picture is the result of var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a little bit delay (few days delay, I solved it at the day I posted this question). Well.. The solution is actually like @Ahmad said, something like a "bridge" page that gets the data and handles it.
This is the Solution:

**C#:**

```
            string url = "http://10.0.0.4/cnc/cs_php/posting.php";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hostname=Nadav" + "&" + "ip=10.0.0.4" + "&" + "os=Windows 10 x64");

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream webpageStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
```

**posting.php**

```
<?php
  $v1 = $_POST["value1"];
  $v2 = $_POST["value2"];
  $v3 = $_POST["value3"];

  $servername = "server name";
  $usernamedb = "DB username";
  $passworddb = "DB password";
  $dbname = "DB name";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $usernamedb, $passworddb, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 if (!empty($host))
 {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO..." //You know... The query of inserting into the table

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
 {
    header("location: index.php");
 }
 else 
 {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

and last one is the index.php which only prints (for me) the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an complete answer, but I'm sending it here because it is too large for  a comment.

I added these codes to the C# code, to get and print the response.

```
var res = new byte[1000];
webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Read(res, 0, 1000);

Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(res));
```

And I got this in the console:

```
???array(2) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(19) "This is the message"
  ["username"]=>
  string(19) "This is the usrname"
}
<html><br/></html>Array
(
    [message] => This is the message
    [username] => This is the usrname
)
<html><br/></html>This is the message<html><br/></html>string(56) "message=This is the message&username=This is the usrn
ame"
<html><br/></html>
```

And as you see, everything seems to be OK. So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your example! I really appreciate that! However, as I showed before, the $_POST does contain the data, but it doesn't show it in the page.

Comment: You're welcome! You said it doesn't show in the **page**. So I think you want to send something from c# to the server, and see it next time you request the same page from a **browser**. Am I right?

Comment: yea... I need it to be printed to the screen using PHP, I need it only once, so I'll be able to insert it to SQL, but it must be with PHP and from the C# the method must be POST.

Comment: The response shows that PHP receives the data you sent in `$_POST`, so you can save it in database or a file. For example you can write `file_put_contents("data.txt", $_POST['message'])`. Next time you can load the data from this file and use it.